# ImageMagick generated PDF renders as blank pages in Chrome

Tags: chrome, pdf, conversion, imagemagick

I have drawn a `png` file using Krita:
[image]

I then converted this file to a `pdf` file using `convert`:

```
convert test.png test.pdf
```

When I open this file in my PDF viewer (Evince), I see the image above, just as I expected. But when I open the file in my web browser (based on Chrome), I see a PDF page in the correct size, but completely blank:
[image]

As far as I can tell, the issue only occurs in Chrome-based browsers. Firefox for example displays the file correctly.

**What can I do so that the file is displayed correctly across browsers?**

---

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-37 Q16 x86_64 2020-11-07 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib

$ chromium --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Chromium 86.0.4240.183 Arch Linux
```

Comment: When I use GIMP for the conversion, the pdf file is rendered correctly.

Comment: Curiously, that same version of Chrome but on windows renders it fine.  `Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you push the PDF from `convert test.png test.pdf` through ghostscript it will tell you that there is an error in the file:

```
$ gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=temp.pdf test.pdf
   **** Error: ICCbased space /N value does not match the ICC profile.
                 Using the number of channels from the profile.
                 Output may be incorrect.
```

With that information I added a colorspace to convert:

```
$ convert test.png -colorspace RGB test.pdf
```

Now Ghostscript no longer complains and Chrome will display the file correctly.